# How to create div container with text and small delete icon in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

Using dynamically created TextBox and Button controls (ASP.NET C# page), I need to write JavaScript function that will (by clicking on button) add text + some small delete icon next to that text (enabling user to delete this text), and place it to some container (div or something).

Don't know if I explained clearly enough, but I want to do create something very similar to this stackoverflow TAGS area (in my case, tags should be created by click on the button).
[image]

Also I have to get those values after post back (write it to database after user submit that page).
Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function addTo(val) 
{ 
  document.getElementById('MainContent_txtbox').value = ""; 
  var lblLink = document.createElement("span"); 
  lblLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));     
  document.getElementById('addItHere1').appendChild(lblLink); 
} 
</script>
```

On click of the button it is shown in div tag

```
Label Labe3 = new Label(); 
Labe3.Text = "<div id=\"addItHere" + itemCounter.ToString() + "\" ></div>";
```

Comment: That sounds like a pretty cool idea! What have you tried so far? Are you having difficulties?

Comment: delete icon has "class", which, after onclick event in body, recognized by js and killed with "delete(target.parentNode)" command or similar.

Comment: @Asad Yes, I create javascript function
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTo(val) {
document.getElementById('MainContent_txtbox').value = "";
var lblLink = document.createElement("span");
lblLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
document.getElementById('addItHere1').appendChild(lblLink);
}
</script>

and on click of the button it is shown in div tag
Label Labe3 = new Label();
Labe3.Text = "<div id=\"addItHere" + itemCounter.ToString() + "\" ></div>";
But I don't know hot to proceed (enable user to delete it, and get those values on postback).

Comment: @EL thank you for the answer, but I didn't understood anything!?

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
<span class="post-tag">text<span class="delete-tag" onclick="delete(this.parentNode);">x</span></span>
```

the next step you should take: learn how to attach onclick for body tag, how to determine target, how to check it's class attribute, compare its value to "delete-tag" etc.